# The Morning Report song in The Lion King

Tags: soundtrack, the-lion-king

I was a child of Disney and we had a VHS copy of the Lion King. I watched it many many times but never saw a song called "[The Morning Report](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGt1qa3VpsY)" with Rowan Atkinson singing as Zazu but it appears on various CDs and soundtracks I've seen since.

Was this song only released in some versions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The song was created when the film was made, but cut for the initial theatrical release.

However, it was added in later for some IMAX and home video releases, mainly due to the song being included in the live Broadway production of The Lion King.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lion_king#Soundtrack

Comment: It's a damn shame that song got cut. One of my favorite additions in the Broadway musical.