# Where is the acoustic Lennon recording of Strawberry Fields from?

Tags: soundtrack, vivir-es-facil-con-ojos-cerrados

In the movie [*Vivir es fácil con los ojos cerrados* (Living Is Easy with Eyes Closed) (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2896036/), the English teacher Antonio makes a recording of John Lennon playing *Strawberry Fields Forever* to him. Antonio gifts the recording to the boy Juanjo, who then plays it on the car on the way back to Madrid.

As far as I can tell, this recording seems authentic ([YouTube upload](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFgrM5_NgXc) of the clip, but with the video altered). (I might be mistaken though and it might just be someone else they got to sing it.)

My question is: What is the source of this recording? (Album/demo tape/etc.)

---

According to the Google-translated description of the YouTube clip I linked to:

> In fact it is Neil Harrison of the Beatles Bootleg who sings and not - if you can believe it - John Lennon. They recorded this version especially for the film to give it a more personal touch since there is no acoustic version of 'Strawberry Fields' that sounds so clear.

But according to a [*Montreal Gazette* movie review](http://www.montrealgazette.com/entertainment/movie-guide/Movie+review+Living+Easy+With+Eyes+Closed/10156953/story.html):

> Near the end of the film, we hear an early acoustic version of the song, in an incredibly moving moment.

---

To the down-voter and close-voter: **I don't think this question is off-topic because this particular recording is a key piece or even climax of the movie.** (If you haven't seen this movie, it is named after a line in the song and ostensibly centers around a Beatles-obsessed English teacher's quest to meet John Lennon. However and significantly, except for this one instance, not a single Beatles song is played in the entire movie.)

Similar questions on this site that haven't been closed: [What is the theme music of Breaking Bad?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14234/what-is-the-theme-music-of-breaking-bad), [The Morning Report song in The Lion King](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13650/the-morning-report-song-in-the-lion-king), [What was the song in Westworld S2E5?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89305/what-was-the-song-in-westworld-s2e5).

Comment: Judging by the quality and style of the early Beatles demos of Strawberry Fields, it is very probably a cover (I imagine the work taken to extract and remaster the vocal track of an unknown authentic authentic recording and overlay a clean guitar track would be beyond the budget of the film). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umxkWMHYPd4) is a recording of the Bootleg Beatles performing Strawberry Fields when Neil Harrison was still a member of the group (pre 2011) for comparison.

Comment: @ukemi: I don't know if it's necessarily a cover. Searching a bit more, I find it sounds very similar to for example Anthology Vol. II > CD2 > Track 01 Strawberry Fields Forever (Demo Sequence). And there are a bunch more other uploads (demos, home recordings) on YouTube that sound similar. So it's not inconceivable that this was one of those demos but perhaps cleaned up a little.